Android MediaPlayer crashes on openFd
I'm using an image's properties to set the boundary for a MediaPlayer. That app crashes with the error below on the line: requireContext().assets.openFd(imagename)
Any thoughts?
player = MediaPlayer().apply {
                                        requireContext().assets.openFd(imagename)
                                            .use { descriptor ->

                                                val metadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
                                                metadataRetriever.setDataSource(
                                                    descriptor.fileDescriptor,
                                                    descriptor.startOffset,
                                                    descriptor.length
                                                )

                                                val videoWidth = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH)
                                                    ?.toFloatOrNull()
                                                    ?: 0f
                                                val videoHeight = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT)
                                                    ?.toFloatOrNull()
                                                    ?: 0f
                                                val videoRotation = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION)
                                                    ?.toFloatOrNull()
                                                    ?: 0f

                                                // Account for video rotation, so that scale logic math works properly
                                                val imageSize = RectF(0f, 0f, augmentedImage.extentX, augmentedImage.extentZ)
                                                    .transform(rotationMatrix(videoRotation))

                                                val videoScaleType = VideoScaleType.CenterCrop

                                                videoAnchorNode.setVideoProperties(
                                                    videoWidth = videoWidth, videoHeight = videoHeight, videoRotation = videoRotation,
                                                    imageWidth = imageSize.width(), imageHeight = imageSize.height(),
                                                    videoScaleType = videoScaleType
                                                )
                                            }

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.github.sceneview.sample.araugmentedimage, PID: 2250
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:588)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: qrcode
at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAssetFd(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:1011)
at io.github.sceneview.sample.araugmentedimage.MainFragment$onViewCreated$1$2.invoke(MainFragment.kt:77)
at io.github.sceneview.sample.araugmentedimage.MainFragment$onViewCreated$1$2.invoke(MainFragment.kt:59)
at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneView.onSessionUpdated(ARSceneView.kt:324)
at io.github.sceneview.ar.ARSceneView.onFrame(ARSceneView.kt:278)
at io.github.sceneview.SceneView$frameCallback$1.doFrame(SceneView.kt:295)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1687)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1698)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1153)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1069)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1646)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 

Obviously you tried to open a file called "qrcode" using AssetManager, but it was not found. Check if this file is in your project or if it is in the correct path.

The file is definitely there but I could be looking in the wrong folder. I'll check that.
